# c# Image.FromFile - Bulk Operation?

Tags: c#, image, file-io

To keep the performance "high", when using our application, we are using (preloaded) imagelists for all the listviews.

The biggeset listview can contain an imagelist of about 9000 images.

So, to generate the imagelist, we used `addRange()` which allows this to finish in about no time.

However, "loading" the images from the filesystem into an `image[]` array, takes still 4-5 seconds during startup. (~ 80 MB, on a SSD)

I wonder if there's a better way to populate "large" imagelists from the (local) filesystem?

Currently we are using:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di2 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Config.ProductImageLocalPath);
System.IO.FileInfo[] files2 = di.EnumerateFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();

int idx = 1; //0 is reservevd for default image, which is already added.
foreach (FileInfo fi in files2)
{
    Resources.ImageIndex.Add(long.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name)), idx++);
}

Image[] images = Array.ConvertAll(files2, file => Image.FromFile(file.FullName));

Resources.ProductImageList_256.Images.AddRange(images);
```

The `ImageIndex` is just a `dictionary<Long, int>` which allows to map the actual `id` (derived from the filename) to the 0-based index in the respective image map and doesn't require any time to be generated.

Obvisouly `Image[] images = Array.ConvertAll(files2, file => Image.FromFile(file.FullName));` is the bottle-neck, as this equals 9000 calls to `Image.fromFile` (Is there some bulk-Option as well?).

Any "better" ideas here?

Comment: I understand you want to have that image list ready but can you split the work and implement techniques used for the web, games, google maps. You basically want to load a subset of what will be immediately visible and load the rest ondemand, task, or backgroundworker. First you can start by making it a List<Image> so you can append, and as long as you are not removing just adding you don't have to worry about concurrency.

Comment: @FelipeRamos loading on demand is a problem with listviews. If you receive a resultset of some thausand elements and start to load individual images "on demand", it will slow the whole rendering down.

Comment: are the images all the size needed for the ListView? If the images are larger than needed for the ListView can you create a subset of thumbnails. I would also `rootDir.EnumerateFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(s=> s.FullName);` just select the names out since it is what you need to avoid keeping a collection of FileInfo in memory. Don't know which version of the framework you are using but you could try a Parallel.ForEeach before messing with Threading.

Comment: @FelipeRamos yes, "Parallel.ForEeach" would have been a great idea :-) (Well, i'm not messing with threads, threads are my beloved companions for ages) - But i'll actually give it a try, if "Parallel.ForEeach" might be more efficent than oldschool work-balancing.

Comment: @FelipeRamos See my update - it's somewhat faster, but more important: way easier to read, understand and maintain :)

Comment: Good deal @dognose I am glad you are seeing some gains - It is looking streamline now. If I find anything else I'll make sure to update the post.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I wrote a function, which will do the job distributed to several threads - and then found a "bug" in my code. (However, using multithreading helps a lot beside that, so `image.fromFile` is clearly bottlenecked by the cpu, not by the (local) SSD).

**1.) Network-Loading**

In the code mentioned above: `System.IO.FileInfo[] files2 = di.EnumerateFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();`
 - i used `di` to be enumerated rather than `di2` (`di` refers to the network share)

(so `Array.ConvertAll` was accessing the remote files)

Runtime of "this" approach: **6s 414ms**

**2.) Local-Loading**

Fixing this lead to the runtime of **1s 886ms**

**3.) Local-Threaded-Loading**

However, my `ThreadedLoading`-Function was already done, so I tried it out as well:

**0s 543ms** - so still almost 4 times faster on a 8-core with 4 physical cores.

Here's the code. Might not yet be bulletproof, but produces reliable and fast(est) results.

usage:

```
 DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
//Image[] images = Array.ConvertAll(files2, file => Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
Image[] images = loadImagesThreaded(files2);
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan ts = t2.Subtract(t1);
MessageBox.Show("Loading took: " + ts.Seconds + "s " + ts.Milliseconds + "ms"); //6s 414ms

Resources.ProductImageList_256.Images.AddRange(images);
```

Function:

```
private Image[] loadImagesThreaded(FileInfo[] files)
{
    int threadCount = 8;
    int chunkSize = files.Length / threadCount; //Round about -  doesn't need to be precise. 
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadCount];
    Image[][] result = new Image[threadCount][];

    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
    {
        FileInfo[] chunk;
        int lowerBound = i * chunkSize;
        if (i < threadCount - 1)
        {
            chunk = files.Skip(lowerBound).Take(chunkSize).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            //take the rest
            chunk = files.Skip(lowerBound).ToArray();
        }

        int j = i; 
        threads[i] = new Thread(() =>
        {
            result[j] = Array.ConvertAll(chunk, file => Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
        });
        threads[i].Start();
    }

    //wait for threads to finish. 
    Boolean oneAlive = true;
    while (oneAlive)
    {
        oneAlive = false;
        foreach (Thread t in threads)
        {
            if (t.IsAlive)
            {
                oneAlive = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //all done. 
    Image[] finalResult = new Image[files.Count()];
    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
    {
        int lowerBound = i * chunkSize;
        result[i].CopyTo(finalResult, lowerBound);
    }
    return finalResult;
}
```

---

isn't that a nice peak, while preloading images? :-)

[image]

---

**4.) Parallel.ForEach**

As recommended by Felipe Ramos, I tried `Parallel.ForEach`. It is about 40-50 ms faster than my "threaded" solution (mostly getting 480-500 ms)- but maybe the more important fact:

It is a no-brainer and therefore more reliable, i'd say.:

```
Image[] images = new Image[files2.Count()];
Parallel.ForEach(files2, (fileInfo, state, index) =>
{
    images[index] = Image.FromFile(fileInfo.FullName);
});

DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ts = t2.Subtract(t1);
MessageBox.Show("Loading took: " + ts.Seconds + "s " + ts.Milliseconds + "ms");
```